# Как вывести дополнительные поля дочерних ресурсов pdoResources MODX Revo?

Tags: modx, вывод, revo, pdoresource, pdotools

Структура ресурсов такая:

```
-Главная страница обучения
---Тема урока 1
-----Урок 1
-----Урок 2
---Тема урока 2
-----Урок 1
-----Урок 2
```

На страницах тем уроков создал доп поля  TV и только их вывожу на главной странице обучения + создал дон поле TV на странице непосредственно каждого урока и это поле тоже вывожу на главной странице обучения.

Получается что главная имеет один id, каждая тема другой id и каждый урок другой id ресурса.

Но проблема в том, что на главной выводятся только поля тем, а уроков нет(((
Так как уроки это дети тем, а они их родители, но главная страница обучения это родитель всех страниц тем и уроков.

Вывод осуществляю так:

```
[[pdoResources?
 &parents=`19` // это id главной стр обучения
 &depth=`0` // это вообще хз что за глубина
 &tpl=`itemsLessons` // чанк обработчика вывода
 &includeTVs=`CountLessons,itemName,lessonName` // поля
 &sortdir=`ASC` // сортировка
]]
```

Как вывести поля детей (уроки) на главной?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Помогли на [тостере](https://toster.ru/q/600191) решить проблему с горем пополам!

В итоге получилось так:

```
[[pdoMenu?
&parents=`19`
&level=`0`
&tpl=`@INLINE 
    <div class="wrapMe clear">
    <div class="itemCount left ttu">тема <span></span> <p><span></span></p></div>
    <div class="lessonsContainer whiteBody right">
    <div class="my_arrow"><img src="theme/img/my_arrow.png" alt="раскрыть тему с уроками" title="раскрыть тему с уроками"></div>
        <div class="countLessons q_number">[[+children]] [[+children:units=`урок|урока|уроков`]]</div>
        <div class="itemName faqman-question">[[+pagetitle]]</div>
        <ul class="lessonsUl">[[+wrapper]]</ul>
    </div>
    </div>`
&tplOuter=`@INLINE [[+wrapper]]`
&tplInnerRow=`@INLINE <li class="lessonName"><a href="[[+link]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a>,</li>`
&countChildren=`1`
]]
```

В общем использовать tv поля было ошибкой, лучше делать все системными методами,

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/332665)

Comment: согласен с Вами